# : pg_exec(): Query failed: ERROR: column &quot;dd&quot;

Tags: php, database

I am trying to get value from where **dd='thiruvallur'** it's working with mysql but can't work with pgsql (please advise for me)

```
include('connection.php');

$value='Thiruvallur';

        echo $result = pg_exec($db,'SELECT "DD" FROM "table name" where "DD"=$value');

    while($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) {

        echo $santh=$row['DD'];

    }
```

Comment: Is your column called `"DD"` with the quote marks?

Comment: SELECT "DD" FROM "table name" where "DD"=thiruvallur .. it execute direct database but programatically single quote problem when passing variable

Answer (score 0):

refer the website like select where condition passing paramter http://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_php.html